# Multiply Matrix element in i-th row by the i-th element in the first row

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
s=[1,2,3; 4,5,6;7,8,9];  

1| 2| 3  
4| 5| 6  
7| 8| 9
```

Now I want each integer in the first row and i-th column to be multiplied by the corresponding `i` row number.

Desired output:

```
1 | 2  | 3  
8 | 10 | 12  
21| 24 | 27
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if A is diagonal matrix, then A*x scales the rows of x by the weights specified by the diagonal in A. So, for your problem you could simply use:

```
s = [1,2,3; 4,5,6;7,8,9];
%  1     2     3
%  4     5     6
%  7     8     9

s = diag([1:size(s,1)]) * s;
%  1     2     3
%  8    10    12
% 21    24    27
```

Comment: Nice one line solution.

Comment: Good one. I have used it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `bsxfun` you can write:

```
bsxfun(@times,s,(1:size(s,1)).')
```

that in MATLAB R2016b or Octave ,thanks to implicit expansion, can be written as:

```
s .* (1:size(s,1)).'
```

Comment: I wonder if there are any questions that cannot be answered with `bsxfun` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
s = [1,2,3; 4,5,6;7,8,9];

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9

[~, y] = size(s);
a = s(ones(y,1),:).';
b = a.*s;

b  = 
  1     2     3
  8    10    12
 21    24    27
```